# Strange function return result

Tags: c++, function

```
float Calculate(const string &query)
{
        std::cout << "Query: " << query << "\n";
        unsigned int size = query.length();
        char stack[70];
        float res;
        int m = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
                if (query[i] >= '0' && query[i] <= '9')
                {
                        stack[m] = query[i] - '0';
                        m++;
                        continue;
                }

                switch (query[i])
                {
                        case '+':
                        {
                                res = stack[m - 2] + stack[m - 1];
                                break;
                        }
                        case '-':
                        {
                                res = stack[m - 2] - stack[m - 1];
                                break;
                        }
                        case '*':
                        {
                                res = stack[m - 2] * stack[m - 1];
                                break;
                        }
                        case '/':
                        {
                                res = stack[m - 2] / stack[m - 1];
                                break;
                        }
                }

                    stack[m - 2] = res;
                m--;
                cout << "RES: " << res << "\n";
        }

        return res;
}
```

It calculates reverse polish notation.

When I call something like: `Calculate("11+")` it returns right result: `2`.

But, when I pass a variable after getting of RPN string:

```
string inputStr;
string outputStr;

cout << "Put exercise\n";
getline(std::cin, inputStr);

outputStr = GetRPN(inputStr);
cout << "Output str :" << outputStr << ":\n";

float res = Calculate(outputStr);
std::cout << res << "\n";
```

So, when I input string: `1+1`, function `GetRPN` returns `11+` and I see that in second cout. But result is `0`!

What could it be?

---

```
string GetRPN(string input)
{
    vector <char> operation;
    string outputStr;      //output string, keep RPN
    int stack_count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
        {
            outputStr += input[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(operation.empty())
            {
                operation.push_back(input[i]);
                stack_count++;
            }
            else if(operation[stack_count - 1] == '+' || operation[stack_count - 1] == '-')
            {
                operation.push_back(input[i]);
                stack_count++;
            }
            else if ((operation[stack_count - 1] == '*' || operation[stack_count - 1] == '/') && (input[i] == '*' || input[i] == '/'))
            {
                outputStr += operation[stack_count - 1]; // move mark of operation to output str
                operation.pop_back(); // delet last element from vector
                operation.push_back(input[i]);// plus new operation mark to vector
                stack_count++;
            }
            else if (operation[stack_count - 1] == '*' || operation[stack_count - 1] == '/')
            {
                outputStr += input[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = operation.size(); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        outputStr += operation[i]; // move all operation marks to otput str
    }

    return outputStr;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any trailing spaces or other "garbage" white-space characters coming back from GetRPN - you might print out the length.

Comment: Not sure what `GetRPN` does, but it could leave a final `\n` or `\r` in the string outputStr, which could not be matched in the `switch (query[i])`, leaving `res` somehow null...

Comment: Your `Calculate()` looks fine and given identical input should output the same result. Can you post your `GetRPN()` function as well?

Comment: I never knew `std::string` has `lenght()` member function which returns the same value as `size()`.

Comment: Final loop of GetRPN looks suspect - don't you want to start at i = operation.size()-1?  If you have a 2 char string, you only want to append elements 1 and 0, not 2, 1, and 0.  This doesn't explain why you're seeing correct output, however.

Comment: @Ockonal: Problems like this are resolved by *debugging* the code. Why are you asking other people to debug your code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cycle here

```
for(int i = operation.size(); i >= 0; i--)
{
    outputStr += operation[i]; // move all operation marks to otput str
}
```

does not make any sense. You are obviously attempting to access the vector at invalid index. It is illegal to access the element at `operation[i]` when `i` is equal `operation.size()`. The index is out of range.

Any self-respecting implementation would immediately report this problem with an assertion. In any case, as I said in the comment, the problems like that are resolved by debugging the code. Why are you asking other people to debug your code instead of doing it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If your string has any whitespace or unprintable characters in it, you'll end up storing into `stack` with a negative index, which will overwrite other stuff in your stack frame and could cause anything to happen.

You should add some error checking to `Calculate` -- the switch should have a `default` that prints a sensible error message, and you should check the value of `m` before accessing `stack[m]` or `stack[m-2]` to make sure the stack doesn't underflow or overflow (and you should print a sensible error if it does.)  You should be able to pass ANY random string to Calculate and have it tell you why its not a valid RPN expression.